# What is the strumming pattern of the song "Underground" from City and Colour

Tags: strumming

Here are the references : [Played acoustic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKnQk_qMgw8)

On [chordify.net](https://chordify.net/chords/city-and-colour-underground-acoustic-city-and-colour)

There we hear 2 rapid strums then some void and then 3 or 4 strums so I would go for DU-UDU-- but that on my electric guitar doesn't ring the same as him. I guess the 2 first strums must be on the big strings and the other on the small ones.

The tab is [here](https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/city-and-colour/underground-chords-4710593)

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, transcription requests [aren't covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).